# updating win32 window to display generated barcode

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, barcode

I am creating a barcode generator application in win32. I got the library to generate the needed barcodes and if I hardcode the UPC it displays the barcode fine. However I want to be able to enter a string in the text field and have it generate the barcode and display it on the window.

I've looked into UpdateWindow, but the HWND variable that is in

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)

is out of scope in the function that I want to call it in, and I've also tried making a global HWND hWnd, but it throws a compiler error.

If this is not enough information, please let me know so I can update it with the necessary information.

Comment: Show the code where the compiler throw an error, and the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have read the error more carefully.

The error was the redefinition of a variable. Just deleted the later definition and the problem went away.

Sorry!